# In Firebase Real Time database, will the .indexOn rule increase the volume of the database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, indexing

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240295/11214643) which states:

> It creates some indexes ahead of time, but you need to tell it when
> you want to query with nested children with orderByChild orderByValue.

Does this mean that the DB multiplies the branch for each .indexOn rule added + 1?

eg:- I have 3 Megs of data on branch A which is indexed by $key.

If I use a rule:

```
"A": {".indexOn":["fieldA", "fieldB"]}
```

Now under the hood Firebase will Create a subbranch of A that will re-insert the indices already found on 'A' but this time under the key defined in the .indexOn rule:

```
A--|
   |__rule_field_a
          |
          |_val_of_field_a_1 -> :value_a
          |
          |_val_of_field_a_2 -> :value_b
          |
          etc... etc...
```

This means that the 2 indexOn rules will multiply the volume of the branch from 3 to 9 Megs.

Is this correct?

Will this get reflected in the pricing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

**Indexes that you define on the Firebase Realtime Database inside your security rules are not stored in your database itself, and you are not charged for them.**

---

If you choose to store such data in the database yourself, you will of course be charged for that. An example of such a use-case would be [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value), but while that is commonly referred to as a reverse or inverted index, it is not declared in your security rules.